# Intercepting Store Kit alert views

Tags: iphone, storekit

When one of my in-app transactions is completed, either because it is restored or because it is a successful purchase, Store Kit generates an alert view that displays a confirmation dialog box. In this current version it says "Thank You. Your Purchase was successful.".

Since my app should move to a different screen after a purchase is successful, I want to intercept that dialog box and not make the transition until it is dismissed by the user. The problem is that I don't seem to have any control over that dialog box. Anyone has any ideas of how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try. Your payment delegate is notified when a purchase goes through--use that mechanism. Those alerts are part of the AppStore.app binary and aren't executed in your process, so you can't touch them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Indeed, my payment delegate (my SKPaymentTransactionObserver class) is notified when the payment is successful. At that point I provide the product and finish the transaction, but whatever happens after that is what I cannot control... And it just happens that it is then when the dialog box is displayed. Is that what you meant or am I missing something?

Comment: That's what I meant. You do not have the ability to dismiss the alert or modify it in any way.

Comment: But surely there's a way to know when the whole process is finished. Not to interfere with that alert, but to at least know when the user has hit okay, no?

Comment: Yes. You register as a delegate in the transaction process. That's the one and only sanctioned way to monitor what's happening.

Comment: This has become even a little more difficult with iOS8 it seems. I have been putting up an alert of my own closely following in time after Apple's "Thank You" alert. Previously (iOS7 and earlier), my alert didn't show until *after* the user dismissed Apple's alert. Now, with iOS8, my alert shows up *behind* Apple's alert. Which looks kinda funky.

Comment: Chris: if you believe that behaviour is incorrect, you should file a bug report at http://bugreporter.apple.com .

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that the app becomes inactive when those StoreKit alerts pop up:

Check UIApplication's activeState property after the purchase is finished if it's 'inactive', then delay your movement to a different screen until the state changes to 'active' again (monitor for UIApplicationDidBecomeActive notification).

'activeState' property is not supported on firmwares older than 4.0, but you can still track app state changes manually and know its state at any time.

Comment: That worked nicely, thanks. If the app is not in active state, I wait until it is in an active state to show the alert. I'll give a snippet of my code below.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested this technique with iOS6, iOS7, and iOS8 and all seems fine.

```
- (void) activeShow;
{
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    if (app.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        [self finishActiveShow];
    } else  {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                selector:@selector(becomeActiveNotification:)
                name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
    }
}

- (void) finishActiveShow;
{
    if (self.beforeShow) {
        self.beforeShow();
    }
    [self.alert show];
    if (self.afterShow) {
        self.afterShow();
    }
}

- (void) becomeActiveNotification:(id) sender;
{
    SPASLog(@"UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification: %@", sender);
    // From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationCenters.html
    // "In a multithreaded application, notifications are always delivered in the thread in which the notification was posted, which may not be the same thread in which an observer registered itself."
    // So, it seems that we may not get the notification on the main thread.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self finishActiveShow];
    });

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. Now, I'm finding that this is flaky. Sometimes (and in fact, it seems most of the time) Apples "Thank You" alert will be displayed and the app *will* be in an active state.